# Why .net Standard 2.0 Point struct only allows int constructor

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, .net-standard

In .net Standard 2.0 I have the Point struct that only accepts 2 ints, X and Y. In Windows we used to have Point with double, as a point can be in a Canvas in X=15.2333 and y= 89.988. Using doubles was pretty convenient, now we have only int, is there any way we can keep having our old Point(double x, double y)?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.point?view=netstandard-2.0

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.pointf?view=netstandard-2.0

Comment: Use PointF : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.pointf?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: System.Drawing uses integral values, sounds like you're confused about WPF's Point type.  Which is not wrapped by .NETStandard.  Just make your own.

Answer (score 0):

As they pointed in the comments PointF is the equivalent of in .net standard, even if it's not a double but a float.

Use PointF : learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/… – jdweng